# Can I set up a session in a WordPress custom page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to set up a login system and a contact form for front-end users of my custom WP theme. I need to create an ajax post method and send the input values to the server (Captcha and input values like name, phone, email, ... ).
Now my question is, do I  have to create a php session to secure unwanted form submission or passing the captcha value between two pages?

If so, is this a correct page template for a contact page and captcha page

```
<?php
session_start();
/*
 Template Name: Contact Page
*/
```

The captcha.php

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to start a session in order to send a captcha, name, phone, or email. However, if you want to remember this information as the user clicks on different pages you will need to start a session.

It is a common convention in WordPress to start the session in your functions.php file.

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
```

Now, on your contact page you can store the information after POST:

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email']
```

And it will be available on different pages in the $_SESSION array.

**Note**: validate and sanitize the $_POST variables. Look into storing a token in your database that is associated with a user id vs storing the users information in the $_SESSION array. Then store the name, phone, and email in your DB.

Comment: Thank Jonathan, This was a perfect hint just one more question? in order to add the session into `function.php` is this the whole code? `if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}` Do I need any action or filter hook for this?

Comment: You don't. The functions.php file is read every time any page is loaded. Front end or back end.